# How to create a multi-language installer with Qt Installer Framework?

Tags: windows, macos, qt, qt-installer

I would like to create a multi-language installer with Qt Installer Framework.

My goal is to have the same used language by the OS. I know that I must put qm files somewhere and modify a xml package like that :

http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-customizing-installers.html#translating-pages

http://doc.qt.io/qtinstallerframework/ifw-component-description.html

My question is where to find generic qm files / how to generate them / where to put it. I wish have a translated installer for all Qt String not my custom Strings cuz I never add new Strings

ps : I discovered that "windeployqt.exe" or "macdeployqt" exe generates a directory named "translations" with a lot of qm files : "qt_en.qm",  "qt_es.qm", "qt_de.qm", "qt_fr.qm", ... I don't know if it's usefull

ps2 : qm file formet is a binary file format not a xml file format or a text file format

Comment: There is huge number of articles regarding this topic. One of the top hits in Google that contains the info you are looking for: https://wiki.qt.io/How_to_create_a_multi_language_application. Come back with a more specific questions.

Comment: I don't talk about a translated application but a translated installer. I dont have/want access to the c++ source code

Answer (score 1):

You can see an example in the installer framework - translations.

1. You need to add a section to the package.xml file. For example:

`<Translations>
     <Translation>de.qm</ Translation>
         <Translation>fr.qm</ Translation>
<Translations>`

2. You need to put translation files near package.xml

Qt will detect your locale at boot time and automatically load the translation. If there is no translation, the English version will be loaded.